# Let user change configuration parameter

Tags: java, web-applications, configuration-files

In Java web application, I have some configuration parameters that I keep in config file. For example frequency of calling a particular method.

I want to let user change this using a UI. So, how and where such parameters should be defined so that user can change them and changed value comes in effect without need to redeployment.

Further explanation:
Lets say I have a java servlet that takes the back up of few files. I have scheduled this to run daily at noon. Now I want to let user change the time at which he wants to run backup using a interface (web page) that allows to specify new time. 
So, how really should I declare this time in application. In a config file ? As a environment variable or something else so that the new changed value comes into effect without deploying the application.

Hope this explains things better.

SOLUTION:

Just to share with everyone... found this post which answers most of my concerns. 
[LINK](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=58225)

Comment: Answer is Yes. But difficult to say anything further without seeing the code.

Comment: This is not an answerable question. It's too broad, and any answer will depend on your application about which you've said nothing. Create some code and come back with a focused, answerable question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Let me try to explain it further with a edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to modify your implementation to achieve this efficiently. Store the parameter for scheduler in your database. Once the user selects from UI, insert into the database.

Now, instead of config file, make your scheduler read from that column in db. No deployment required.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yea that should work. Is there any other way we can achieve this without using DB ?

Comment: Property files. Won't require a redeployment, but are prone to errors as compared to DB approach.

Comment: So to achieve this using properties files . When user changes the value, we will effectively be modifying/rewriting that value in the properties file ? And how is it not a good practice ?

Comment: And don't we need to reload the properties file ? Is there any way to auto reload ?

Comment: Unless you are caching the values, you don't need to reload. You refer to them everytime your program executes. For any modification you need to write back to file.

Comment: Thanks! .. not able to upvote your answers as I am new here (need at least 15 reputation)... But anyways I think using DB must be more secure and better approach by all means .. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Yes.. writing to db is the better approach. Rather secure and reliable.